# Difference in the three methods for unnumbered equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

What is the (subtle) difference between the three ways to typeset unnumbered equations (if any)?

The first is the plain tex,

```
$$ E = mc^2 $$
```

The second is the LaTeX

```
\[ E = mc^2 \]
```

And the third is the AMS,

```
\begin{equation*}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation*}
```

As far as I can tell, the end results are almost the same. If there's any difference, most likely in the spacing around the formulas. But I cannot find any concrete reference for the later two.

Comment: With `\usepackage{amsmath}`, methods 2 and 3 are exactly the same.